# What do I need to include in my header file for ostream

Tags: c++, header, g++

When I try to compile my program the compiler complains about this line in a .h file that I #included.

```
ostream & Print (ostream & stream);
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you `#include <ostream>`, `ostream` will be defined in the `std` namespace:

```
#include <ostream>

// ...

std::ostream & Print (std::ostream & stream);
```

Comment: If your program's not enormous, just put 'using std::ostream' after the #include ; life and lines are both too short to type std:: more than you have to

Comment: Better may be #include <iosfwd>, that contains only forward declarations.

Comment: @Tom Womack: NEVER EVER put using statements in a header file. Life is way to short to sort out the trouble that that will cause when it blows up in your face.

Answer (score 3):

Use 'using' if you don't want to pull the whole std namespace, eg :

```
#include <iosfwd>
using std::ostream;
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal code for this declaration to compile:

```
#include <iosfwd>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: You shouldn't put `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: Agreed. But I didn't say this code was going into a header file. If you don't have control over the contents of the header file being included, these two lines will get it working from the .cpp file.

Regardless, <iosfwd> is a better choice than <ostream> in this case.